How to inject a List<String> parameter as a text array into a non-IN native query in Spring Data JPA?
There is something I really don't understand about JPA @Query params injection: I would expect any List<String> to
become a {...,...}::TEXT (or ::VARCHAR) in SQL since it's the obvious way to represent a list of strings in SQL.
@Query(
    """
    SELECT ... FROM ...
    WHERE sql_function(:myParam)
                       ^^^ I expect that to be injected as '{a,b,c,etc}'
    """,
    nativeQuery = true,
)
fun findAll(myParam: List<String>): List<...>

Manual Query Check
jsonb_contains_any(jsonb_data jsonb, collection_path text[], collection_key text, search_values text[]) is a custom
PostgreSQL function that I wrote. It is heavily tested and works as expected when I run it manually:
SELECT * FROM logbook_reports
WHERE log_type = 'PNO' AND jsonb_contains_any(value, '{catchOnboard}', 'species', NULL);
SELECT * FROM logbook_reports
WHERE log_type = 'PNO' AND jsonb_contains_any(value, '{catchOnboard}', 'species', '{}');
SELECT * FROM logbook_reports
WHERE log_type = 'PNO' AND jsonb_contains_any(value, '{catchOnboard}', 'species', '{HKE}');


Successfully run. Total query runtime: 258 msec.
1 rows affected.

First Attempt
First I was hoping that this would work out of the box:
@Query(
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM logbook_reports
    WHERE log_type = 'PNO'
      AND jsonb_contains_any(value, '{catchOnboard}', 'species', (:specyCodes))
    """,
    nativeQuery = true,
)
fun findAll(specyCodes: List<String>): List<LogbookReportEntity>

After a specyCodes=['HKE'] request, I get this error:
24-04-11 19:39:58.973 DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : After request [GET /bff/v1/prior_notifications?specyCodes=HKE]
24-04-11 19:39:58.974 ERROR o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog                     : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [
        SELECT *
        FROM logbook_reports
        WHERE log_type = 'PNO' AND jsonb_contains_any(value, '{catchOnboard}', 'species', (?))
        ] [ERROR: function jsonb_contains_any(jsonb, unknown, unknown, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 83] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

You'll notice that it doesn't even "understand" that 'species' is obviously a TEXT type. What else could it be ? And
I wonder how it's able to get lost about something that Postgre understands natively (manual query)?
Second Attempt
I then tried to cast all the parameters:
@Query(
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM logbook_reports
    WHERE log_type = 'PNO'
      AND jsonb_contains_any(value, ARRAY['catchOnboard'], CAST('species' AS TEXT), CAST(:specyCodes AS TEXT[]))
    """,
    nativeQuery = true,
)
fun findAll(specyCodes: List<String>): List<LogbookReportEntity>

Same request (specyCodes=['HKE']):
24-04-11 19:48:02.601 DEBUG o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : After request [GET /bff/v1/prior_notifications?specyCodes=HKE]
24-04-11 19:48:02.605 ERROR o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog                     : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: JDBC exception executing SQL [
        SELECT *
        FROM logbook_reports
        WHERE jsonb_contains_any(value, ARRAY['catchOnboard'], CAST('species' AS TEXT), CAST((?) AS TEXT[]))
        ] [ERROR: malformed array literal: "HKE"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

It just injects 'HKE' as if it was a simple string...
